# Number of ways to select subsets to cover the original set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

Suppose $S$ is a set with $n$ elements. Let $U=\{T|T\subseteq S\text{ and }|T|=k\}$, i.e., $U$ is the set of all possible subsets of $S$ with cardinality $k$. Clearly $|U|=\binom{n}{k}$. Then how many ways are there to select $m$ subsets, such that the union of these subsets is $S$?

My attempt basically takes advantage of the inclusion-exclusion principle. The number of distinct ways to select $m$ subsets from $U$ is
$$\binom{\binom{n}{k}}{m}.$$
We subtract the combination of subsets which does not include one element of $S$. For $x\in S$, the number of subsets which does not contain $x$ is $\binom{n-1}{k}$, so we should subtract
$$n\binom{\binom{n-1}{k}}{m}.$$
We then add the combinations that does not include two elements of $S$. Similarly, we add
$$\binom{n}{2}\binom{\binom{n-2}{k}}{m}.$$
Repeat this procedure until $\binom{n-j}{k}<m$, where $j$ is the number of elements in $S$ that are not contained in the subset. So, at last, the answer to the problem is
$$\Large\sum\limits_{\begin{matrix}j=0\\\binom{n-j}{k}\ge m\end{matrix}}^{n}{(-1)}^j\binom{n}{j}\binom{\binom{n-j}{k}}{m}.$$
But I'm not quite satisfied to this answer. Is there a closed form of this expression? Or has this problem be well-studied? Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty certain you have found the most satisfying form of the answer. There is one mistake; you forgot the $(-1)^j$ factor. Less importantly, there is no need to specify $\binom{n-j}k\ge m$ in the subscript; any terms with $\binom{n-j}k<m$ are automatically zero, so there is no harm in including them.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1429122/177399) comes to the same conclusion.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks, I've fixed the formula.